# How to round based on the 3rd decimal

Tags: javascript

**Question**

I want to round a number to the lowest number based on its 3rd decimal.

For an example

If the number is `6.1064` I want to output `6.10` rather than `6.11`
and if the number is `5.9407` I want to output `5.94`

**Current situation**

I currently use `Math.round` but it rounds `6.1064` as `6.11` which is not what Im after.

How do I do this is Javascript?

Comment: `Math.round(6.1064)` gives you `6.11`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(Math.floor(6.1065 *100)/100).toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).

```
Math.floor(1.9)
1
```

But if you want to to the 100ths place, multiply by 100, floor, divide by 100.

```
var num = 6.1064;
Math.floor((num*100))/100;
6.1
```

To make it show 6.10 instead of 6.1, use [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
var num = 6.1064;
var floor = Math.floor((num*100))/100;
floor.toFixed(2)
"6.10"
```